# How to append data to csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to append data to csv file. I get that data from user using html form. My current code adds data to csv file but it does not append. So when user enters their detail hit register button then it erase the previously added data the insert the new one in that place. So how can I append new data so that it saves in the next row and keeps the rest of the data in place?

Here is what I am doing.

```
full_name = params["full_name"]
email = params["email"]
phone = params["phone"]
organization = params["organization"]
job = params["job"]
diet = params["diet"]
address = params["address"]
code = params["code"]
city = params["city"]
cost_pool = params["cost_pool"]

CSV.open("participants_info.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [full_name, email, phone, organization, job, diet, address, code, city, cost_pool]
end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? If its 1.9.x and since FasterCSV is the built-in CSV library, you could do `require 'csv'` and then  `CSV.open("participants_info.csv","a")` which will append to the file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ``a'' Write-only, starts at end of file if file exists, otherwise
> creates a new file for writing.
>
> ``a+''    Read-write, starts at end of
> file if file exists, otherwise creates a new file for reading and
> writing

use `CSV.open("participants_info.csv", "a+")`

Comment: Just 'a' is better. 'a+' is misleading since you can't really read from it.

Comment: Also if the OP is using Ruby 1.8.7 then "a" won't work, you'll get the following error `ArgumentError: 'mode' must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb'`

Comment: @Anand What do those modes mean by the way?

Comment: @Andrei r == read, rb == read binary, w == write, wb == write binary. The binary/non-binary distinction is only meaningful on windows

Answer (score 4):

Open file in append mode (ab)

```
CSV.open("participants_info.csv", "ab") do |csv|
#...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
File.open('filename', 'a'){ |outfile|
  CSV::Writer.generate(outfile) do |csv|
    csv << ['c1', nil, '', '"', "\r\n", 'c2']
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To append file use the following code:

`CSV.open("participants_info.csv", "ab") do |csv|`