# Store deleted records from database to a CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, sinatra

There are nearly 1 million User records, so we are removing non-active users to maintain table consistency. We are using the Sinatra framework.

In our model :

```
class UserInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def delete_expired_users
    begin
      @expired_users = UserInfo.where("status != ? and UEndDate < ?", "active", 3.months.ago )      

      @expired_users.find_each do |user|  # as we have 500k records to delete, used "find_each" IS THIS ASYNCHRONOUS WAY TO DELETE?
        user.destroy
        # I NEED TO STORE THIS DESTROYED USER IN A CSV FILE.
      end

    rescue
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: First store in CSV then destroy. I don't see any problem. You don't know how to write CSV?

Comment: Because you probably don't want to keep a CSV file open for the entire transaction, you will probably want to append to an existing file. Check this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11426925/385532

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev  I store record first in CVS and then destroy, what if in some case destroy failed? so my csv will not contain accurate deleted records right.

Comment: If destroy failed just delete last line in your CSV. If it is into transaction, delete every line that was created in this trnsaction.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev  Ok. Also I have used "find_each" to delete 50 lacs records. is this asynchronous process? If not, can you please suggest me asynchronous process to delete 50 lacs record?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what do you mean by `async` in this case. I bet you need to read this spec: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev , as our application will be responsible to handle "delete operation" from many different users through API, or some Scheduler at the same time, we planned to put the jobs in queue and then delete from the queue. so I meant "Async" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
as I am not sure with `paranoia gem` is supported in Sinatra or not. I found another best option for both Rails/Sinatra..

Use **[`gem "paper_trail"`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)**
PaperTrail lets you track changes to your models' data. It's good for auditing or versioning. You can see how a model looked at any stage in its lifecycle, revert it to any version, and even undelete it after it's been destroyed.

In order to configure `PaperTrail` for usage with **[Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)**, your Sinatra app must be using ActiveRecord 3 or 4. It is also recommended to use the **[Sinatra ActiveRecord Extension](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord)** or something similar for managing your applications `ActiveRecord` connection in a manner similar to the way `Rails` does.

---

**Old Answer:**

I guess you should look at **[`gem "paranoia"`](https://github.com/radar/paranoia)** once, which is similar as your main goal. (Keep tracking of Deleted Object)

when you called `destroy` on an Active Record object that it didn't actually `destroy` it, but just **hide** the record. `Paranoia` does this by setting a `deleted_at` field to the current time when you `destroy` a record, and hides it by scoping all queries on your model to only include records which do not have a `deleted_at` field.

If you wish to actually destroy an object you may call `really_destroy!`

Comment: Is the 'paranoia' gem compatible with Sinatra? Or is it only for Rails?